# Next-i18Next Blocking Global State in NextJS

Tags: next.js, recoiljs, next-i18next

I am using RecoilJS to pass global state between two pages in Next. This works fine, until I use next-i18next in the page receiving the variables. If I comment out the next-i18next code in the getServerSideProps of the receiving page, the Recoil atoms get passed correctly.

```
export const getServerSideProps = withAuthUserSSR({ whenUnauthed: 
AuthAction.REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN,})(async ({ AuthUser, req, locale }) => {
    return {
        props: {
            // ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale,
            //     [
            //         'sidebar',
            //         'search',
            //         ...
            //     ]
            // )),
        },
    };
})
```

However, I uncomment out this code, *one* of my variables get blocked. I do need to use next-i18next. Can anyone explain why it's getting blocked?

I have three Recoil atoms and am using recoil-persist to persist the data between pages as I understand Recoil doesn't do this normally:

```
import { recoilPersist } from 'recoil-persist'
import { atom } from "recoil";
const { persistAtom } = recoilPersist({ key: 'RSKatom' })

export const newUser = atom({
    key: "newUser",
    default: false,
    effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtom],
})

export const newUserAvatar = atom({
    key: "newUserAvatar",
    default: null,
    effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtom],
})

export const newName = atom({
    key: "newName",
    default: "",
    effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtom],
})
```

What is unusual it that 'newUser' and 'newName' do both get passed, but 'newUserAvatar' does not. This is used to store the value of a file input field, and when the next-i18next code is uncommented out 'newUserAvatar' always becomes an empty object and is console logged as 'RECOIL AVATAR:  {}'

With the code commented out as above, it works, this is the console.log:

```
RECOIL AVATAR:  File {name: 'sample-avatar.jpeg', lastModified: 1639308280770, lastModifiedDate: Sun Dec 12 2021 19:24:40 GMT+0800 (Central Indonesia Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 14744, …}
```

Can anyone please help?

EDIT: I don't think this is specific to Recoil. I tried React Context API as well, with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer and wasn't sure of the etiquette for posting an answer to my own question so looked up [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and this seems the best way to do it.

It seems its related to a bug detailed [here](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/1075) in which 'Navigating between pages with or without translations causes _app remounts'. By including 'serverSideTranslations' on the first page sending the global variables, it stops the app remounting, which was causing data to be lost.